# Using special characters like # and ' in Ajax URL string query

Tags: ajax

I am encountering an issue where special characters like # are causing this script to fail...

it's the postvar variable that contains the special characters,

I am not very familiar with JS programming and I am hoping someone can show me the code needed to deal with an # character in the postvar variable...

thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nocache = 0;
function insert<?php echo $link; ?>() {

        document.getElementById('insert_response<?php echo $link; ?>').innerHTML = "Just a second..."
        var postvar= encodeURI(document.getElementById('<?php echo $link; ?>').value);
        nocache = Math.random();

        http.open('get','ajquery.php?postvar='+postvar+'&nocache = '+nocache+'&field='+'<?php echo $link; ?>'+'&page='+'<?php echo $_GET[page]; ?>'+'&id='+'<?php echo $_GET[id]; ?>'+'&theme='+'<?php echo $rowxxx[THEME]; ?>'+'&table='+'<?php echo $ajaxtable; ?>'+'&q1='+'<?php echo $q1; ?>'+'&q2='+'<?php echo $q2; ?>');
        http.onreadystatechange = insertReply<?php echo $link; ?>;
        http.send(null);

}

function insertReply<?php echo $link; ?>() {
        if(http.readyState == 4){
                var response = http.responseText;
                document.getElementById('insert_response<?php echo $link; ?>').innerHTML = ''+response;
        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using decodeURI() in your insertReply method.

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you show me an example of how that would look in my code? sorry! the syntax is the part that i am struggling with, i don't know javascript very well...

Comment: $link is the name of the div field, generated by a PHP MySQL query, to keep it unique, since I have several of these running on the same page.